# Create a function called "firstletter" that takes one string as a parameter. Then in the function, print the first letter of that string

Tags: python, parameters

My code for the above problem statement is:

```
def firstletter(x):
    x=input()
    print(x[0])
firstletter()
```

But I'm getting this error

```
Oops, your solution is incorrect.

TypeError: firstletter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

can anyone help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to this is:

```
def firstletter(x):
    print(x[0])
```

because the compiler already had custom input it was just checking whether the function had a parameter passed, and one character is taken or not.

p.s.: in udemy we are not able to see if there are test cases or custom inputs.

Answer (score 2):

your function isn't taking any parameters at the moment. Below is a link to some documentation that explains what functions and function parameters are.

[python functions](https://pythonbasics.org/functions/)

Comment: I saw that and updated it with my new code, but some other error is coming

Comment: good job. When you call the function ```firstletter()``` on line 4 you need to tell it what you want your value of ```x``` to be. HINT: think about where you're currently telling python what to set x as.

Comment: Well based on what  you said, I came up with this `def firstletter(x):
    print(x[0])
firstletter( x=input())
`  but this error is coming "EOF when reading a line"